# How to find the highest and lowest value between two custom time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Lets say I have `time_1=time[100]` and `time_2=time[1000]`, is there any way to find the highest and lowest values between `time_1` and `time_2`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there is an easier way to achieve this, but you can calculate the spread between those two bars (how many bars are between those inputs) and then run the `ta.highest()` function on that spread. After that, you'll return the the result of the minimum bar between them.

In your example, you'll calculate the highest of the last 900 bars, and then `plot` the result 100 bars ago:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
time_1 = input.int(100)
time_2 = input.int(1000)

sp = math.abs(time_1-time_2)
highest = ta.highest(high, sp)

plot(highest[math.min(time_1, time_2)])
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not seem to be working as expected.